# Zend Framework 3 tutorial error

Tags: zend-framework3

I just started yesterday the [Zend Framework 3 tutorial](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/overview/)

But, [at this step](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/database-and-models/) :

when I had the module 'Album' in `modules.config.php` I had this following error :

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException
/var/www/api/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php:133
A plugin by the name "getServiceLocator" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager
#0 /var/www/api/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/PluginManager.php(98): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('getServiceLocat...', NULL)
#1 /var/www/api/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(258): Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager->get('getServiceLocat...', NULL)
#2 /var/www/api/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(273): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->plugin('getServiceLocat...')
#3 /var/www/api/module/Album/src/Album/Controller/AlbumController.php(104): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->__call('getServiceLocat...', Array)
#4 /var/www/api/module/Album/src/Album/Controller/AlbumController.php(104): Album\Controller\AlbumController->getServiceLocator()
#5 /var/www/api/module/Album/src/Album/Controller/AlbumController.php(16): Album\Controller\AlbumController->getAlbumTable()
#6 /var/www/api/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(78): Album\Controller\AlbumController->indexAction()
#7 /var/www/api/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(271): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 /var/www/api/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(151): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#9 /var/www/api/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(105): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 /var/www/api/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(119): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#11 /var/www/api/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(271): Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#12 /var/www/api/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(151): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#13 /var/www/api/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(332): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#14 /var/www/api/public/index.php(48): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#15 {main}
```

Can anyone help me please, I really don't understand, I just follow the tuto.
Thanks !

```
namespace Album;

use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;

return [

    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'album' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/album[/:action[/:id]]',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\AlbumController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],

    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: @Cochou Please give your `module/Album/config/module.config.php`.

Comment: @AlFonce thanks for answering ! Here :

Comment: @AlFonce : I restart everything and It's working now, thanks !

Comment: I think you have wrong in module.php file

Answer (score 0):

In your `AlbumController` class, you call `getServiceLocator()`, but you should not have to do it. Are you sure you are following the official ZF3 tutorial? There is no `getServiceLocator()` call in this tutorial. You should not have to retrieve the Service Manager from a controller, as you should inject the necessary services in the controller (it's the ZF3 way to do).

I strongly suggest you to remove from your code all that it is not in the tutorial. Once you'll finish it (including the *In-depth tutorial*), you will understand why you really should not have to call some `getServiceLocator()` method from your controllers...

Answer (score 0):

'view_manager' => [ // setting the views 
        'display_not_found_reason' => true, // it controls whether to display the detailed info about the Page not Found error.
        'display_exceptions'       => true, //it defines whether to display info about an unhandled exception and its stack trace

```
    //*** the two parameters shown above MUST be set to FALSE in production systems, because you don't want the site visitors see the details about errors in you site. 
    ////However, you will still be able to retrieve the detailed information from Apache's error.log file

    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',  //defines the TEMPLATE NAME for the 404 error(it will be searched on template_map)
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index', //defines the TEMPLATE NAME for the unhandled exception error 
    'template_map' => [
        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/default.phtml',

        'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',            
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ],
    'template_path_stack' => [
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ],
],
```

---

As you can see on the lines above, you've some mistakes on your code. Your nesting as a key your Route inside the  'template_path_stack' key which belongs to the '**view_manager**' key. Try to change your code and good luck.